# Graph for android and iOS with multi colour area plotting line graph

Tags: android, ios, plot, graph, area

I need a line/area graph with multi colour as like the picture below. is there any graph library or something? I need it both android and iOS.

Here is the sample image of graph

[image]

or is there any simple lib, which I can edit and modify to this ???

Comment: what do you use for iso and android development?

Comment: Need is mother of invention. Invent something.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 is there any simple lib, which I can edit and modify???

Comment: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts  for iOS and for android it is https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart  this might help you....try extracting only the code which is required your project and use .....it is a little bit tricky but in the end it will save you time.......

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Answer (score 0):

U can use HighCharts. Its a very useful library currently used by these industry gaints [companies using HighCharts](https://stackshare.io/highcharts). Moreover its SDK's are available for both android and iOS. U can find useful references below :

[Highcharts android sdk](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android)

[Highcharts android code sample](https://www.highcharts.com/android/demo)

[Highcharts iOS sdk](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios)

[Highcharts iOS code samples](https://www.highcharts.com/ios/demo)

Answer (score -1):

you can use [highcharts.com](https://www.highcharts.com/demo) demo for create custom charts with lots of styles,

1). select any demo you want to add in your chart

2). click on **EDIT IN JSFIDDLE** button

then the online editor opens and on that page you have 2 editors one is HTML and one is JavaScript editor

copy both the data and arrange in HTML Format and put your dynamic string converted data between it and print it on **webView** in android

[Note: you compulsory have the **internet connection**, and also use **WebView** to load the HTML data]

Example:

Link which i Edit the example

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-log-axis/

Android Studio Code

```
webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadData(getHtmlUrl(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

function getHtmlUrl()

```
public String getHtmlUrl() {
        htmlUrl = "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "<script src=\"https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js\"></script>" +
                "<script src=\"https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js\"></script>" +
                "<script src=\"https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js\"></script>" +
                "" +
                "<div id=\"container\" style=\"min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto\"></div>" +
                "</head>" +
                "<body>" +
                "Highcharts.chart('container', {" +
                "" +
                "    title: {" +
                "        text: 'Logarithmic axis demo'" +
                "    }," +
                "" +
                "    xAxis: {" +
                "        tickInterval: 1" +
                "    }," +
                "" +
                "    yAxis: {" +
                "        type: 'logarithmic'," +
                "        minorTickInterval: 0.1" +
                "    }," +
                "" +
                "    tooltip: {" +
                "        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br />'," +
                "        pointFormat: 'x = {point.x}, y = {point.y}'" +
                "    }," +
                "" +
                "    series: [{" +
                "        data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]," +
                "        pointStart: 1" +
                "    }]" +
                "});" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";
        Log.d("htmlUrl", htmlUrl);
        return htmlUrl;
    }
```

[Note: This Example is Just for android, you can use same for IOS too.]